# jQuery, input elements with the same data attribute value but one is hidden, fill in same data on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

jQuery, input elements with the same data attribute value but one is hidden, fill in same data on keyup.

I have 2 forms on a page with dynamically created form fields from a database via .NET MVC.
I have one form visible and one form that is hidden.

I know how to copy, on keyup, the values from one form field to another IF I have known element classes or Id's.  This is not the case on dynamically created fields.  I can not guarantee that all fields will come back in the same order in each form.

So what I did was I created a 'data' attribute and output the "Model.Name" on the input field.   In my case I am lucky enough that the 2 forms have fields with the same "Model.Name" values. So I am able to do a match on that. But since the forms are built dynamically I need a few things to happen and I need some pointers.

1. I need to know how to copy field inputted values from the visible form fields to their matching hidden form fields with the same "data" attribute value.  I won't necessarily know the actual data-attribute value since the input fields are getting created dynamically.
   How would this work to get the matching form fields.

I have a basic JS Fiddle set up.
https://jsfiddle.net/mb91ktbg/6/

HTML

```
<!--I know the class of the wrapping form -->
 <!--All data values are dynamic, so I don't know then on page load-->
  <div class="masterFieldWrapper">
    <!--Need to copy these input values to the sub field wrapper input values-->
 <label>Field one</label>
<input type="text" data-myattribute="dynamicvalue" />
<label>Field Two</label>
<input type="text" data-myattribute="dynamicvalue2" />
<label>Field Three</label>
<input type="text" data-myattribute="dynamicvalue3" />

 <!--I know the class of the sub field wrapper-->
  <!--I would like to copy the inserted values from the parent wrapper fields to the sub field wrapper fields with the same data-myattribute value-->
 <!--I can not assume the fields come back in the same order. This is why I need to use the data attribute value-->
<div class="subFieldWrapper">
<label>Field One</label>
<input type="text" data-myattribute="dynamicvalue" />
  <label>Field Two</label>
<input type="text" data-myattribute="dynamicvalue2" />
  <label>Field Three</label>
<input type="text" data-myattribute="dynamicvalue3" />
</div>

</div>
```

jQuery Started but not working. need some help please.

```
  $(".masterFieldWrapper input").each(function() {
    var fieldVal = $(this).val();
    var fieldDataAttr = $(this).data("myattribute");
    console.log(fieldDataAttr);
    $(this).keyup(function() {
              $(this).parent('.masterFieldWrapper').find(".subFieldWrapper input").data("myattribute").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Assuming that the forms are identical, you could select all the inputs, find which index is the one you keyup on with $(this) and then use that index to find the correct field in the other form to fill in the value.

Comment: There is actually an issue with that.  I can't necessarily assume the forms will comeback in the exact same order.  I thought about the index solution, but then came the issue where we found out the forms could potentially not come back in the same order.  The only consistency between them is the Model.Name value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would help but, you could dynamically add a class or id to the element and then access like so:

```
 $(".bodyWrapper").on("change", ".form-control", event => {

            let value = $('.dynamicValueInput').val();
            $('.dynamicValueInputCopy').val(value);
            console.log(`body-input-has-changed`);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this :)

var mainForm = $(".masterFieldWrapper");
var Input_type = $("input[type='text']");
var Totalinputs = mainForm.find(Input_type).length;
var Visible_inputs = Totalinputs/2;


var  auto_fulfill = function(){
  for(i=Visible_inputs; i<Totalinputs;i++){
    Input_type.eq(i).val(Input_type.eq(i-Visible_inputs).val());
  }
}

Input_type.keyup(function(){
 auto_fulfill();
})
```

Comment: Doesn't this look at the index of the element. Like I mentioned to a comment above, I can not assume the index of each element will be in the same order.  This is kind of why I want it by the data-attribute value.